# Custom Loss Function on a Keras Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, keras, loss-function

I'm training a Neural Network on Keras to predict class as a triplet of the form `S,P,T`, where `S`, `P` and `T` have different values. The output of the Neural Network is one joint triplet.

In my training data, not all entries of the triplet are tagged for all the samples, i.e. for some samples you can find the y value to be `s1,_,t1` or `_,p2,_` and so on.

I would like to implement a custom loss function that accepts this empty values. I found this example:

```
def masked_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    mask = K.cast(K.not_equal(y_true, mask_value), K.floatx())
    return K.binary_crossentropy(y_true * mask, y_pred * mask)
```

My problem is: the `y_pred` and the `y_true` are one-hot encoded tensors, so before I compare `y_pred` and `y_true` I need to decode them and then compare the inner parts of the triplet.

How can I implement this?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @sziraqui no, I tried but since `y_true` and `y_pred` are symbolic tensors there is no way (or I didn't find it) to cast the value of the tensor to the value of the class I need and then only use the oned that are not missing.